# How to scale the size of textbox in Windows c# form

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

What I'm trying to do here is to have a textbox that'll grow in size as the tool is maximized. 
This is the default size:
[image]

This is when I increase the size of the form:
[image]

I have used 'Anchor' property for this. Under the 'Target Database' section, the server has **Top** Anchor property set. While for it's textbox, **Top, Left, Right** is used.

What exactly I want is for the textbox to grow in size to the right and also move to right.

Is it possible? Please suggest ways to do it. Thanks in advance.

**EDITED**

Can I change the location of a control in c# when it has left anchor property?

Comment: I would suggest you to use `Dock` property along with `TableLayoutPanel` control

Comment: _grow in size to the right and also move to right._ ?? Now which? Or in what ratio? I widen the from by 100 pixels. What should happen to the location and the size???

Answer (score 0):

The `anchor` property tells the runtime to which edges of the window (or the parent control) it keeps the distance constant when the parent size changes.

To have the text box grow, "top, left, right" is the right choice, but the label should at least also have "left" (besides top) added, or it won't move the same way.

I would suggest you add a groupbox for each of your sides, this will probably make things a bit easier, as then each of the two sides are independent. You will probably need "top, left, right, bottom" for the boxes and then "top, left right" for all input controls and "top, left" for the labels. (Hint: "top, left, right, bottom" is not the same as "fill")

Comment: While using groupboxes, the left side box gets overridden by the right side box. As the anchor properties for both has 'Top, Left, Right, Bottom'.

Comment: You're right. Use a `SplitContainer` instead. I've just tried it out: Filled a form with a SplitContainer set to "top, left, bottom, right" and a text box with a label in each part. The text box has "top, left, right" and the label "top, left" and I think it now works as you want it.

Comment: Can I change the location of a control in c# when it has left anchor property?

Comment: @CodeKaro: You mean using code? Yes, that should work. I suggest you to not use code to change locations unless you absolutely have to, because it is very difficult to get things right when designer/code changes interleave.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a smart logic in using its `Dock` ,`Anchor` properties. Better you have your controls in any suitable Layout Panel .

you can also use the [SetBounds()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setbounds.aspx) method in the resize event if you maximize window with pre-defined resolution .

You also can read about managing it with Dock and Anchor properties [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/) and [here](https://www.sellsbrothers.com/writing/winformsAutoScaling.htm) .But you need to be careful about moving controls too.

Comment: Consider summarising those foreign links to improve readability.  Links tend to break with time.  _[when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)_